# Excel Reference Cell value

Tags: excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfspreadsheet

I am trying to read the values from excel A which has the referenced data from another excel sheet B.

Code so far:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read"
            src="#ExpandPath(".")#/Excel_A.xlsx"
            sheetname="Sheet1"
            columns="15-19"
            rows="6-7"
            query="qResult" />

<cfdump var="#qResult#">
```

**Dump Result** : The values in all the columns are not displayed correctly.

[image: Reference Cell Issue]

Tried accessing one of the values through spreadsheet functions; still the same issue exists.

```
<cfscript>
    theSheet = SpreadSheetRead("#ExpandPath(".")#/Excel_A.xlsx","Sheet1");      
    theValue=SpreadsheetGetCellValue(theSheet,10,1);
    theFormula=SpreadsheetGetCellFormula(theSheet,10,1);
    WriteOutput("The value is: " & theValue & " and formula is" & theFormula);  
</cfscript>
```

**Output**: The value is: Sheet1!$A$1 and formula is Sheet1!$A$1

It looks like spreadsheet functions does not support the reference data values.

How can I access the values from the excel cells having referenced data?

**Edit 1:** Steps to replicate what I want.

1. There are two Excel sheets (Excel_A.xlsx and Excel_B.xlsx).
2. Excel_B.xlsx : Insert a number 123 in cell A1.
3. Excel_A.xlsx : Reference the A1 cell of Excel_B in Cell A10. So formula in A10 will be

`='Path to [Excel_B.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1`

4. Now I need to see the value of cell A10 in excel_A programmatically.

How can I achieve this since the `<cfscript>` code is not returning the value and shows just the half-formula?

Comment: I'm pretty confused by your question. Are you saying that the value is a reference or a formula? If it is a reference to a cell/col, then you need to read *both* sheets in so you can dynamically fetch the second value.

Comment: I'm with Ray - this looks like a format to a reference. MTD! is a call for "Month to date" I think (not sure). So you need the value specified by the reference - sheet number 3 or 4 I'd wager.

Comment: @RaymondCamden More details added as part of Edit 1.

Comment: @MarkAKruger : MTD is not the formula, its a sheetname. Details to replicate the issue added as part of Edit 1.